# Syncing ipod to itunes

Tags: itunes, ipod

I have an iPod that has been in use for some time.

I now want to sync it to iTunes on my macbook pro so I can copy some songs from the macbook to the iPod.

when I connect the iPod to the macbook it comes up saying

```
welcome to your new iPod
```

The only options are to set up as a new iPod or restore from a backup, neither of which are what I am trying to do.

is there are way to get this to work the way I am wanting? or is there an alternative way to get songs into the music section on the iPod without syncing with the mac?

Comment: You can only synch in one direction, to the device.  The reason has to do with how easily libraries would be traded if you could synch in either direction at anytime (this is a trade off for not having the music DRM encoded to prevent "trading").   That said google is your friend, there are ways to get you music back to the computer (if you don't still have the original iTunes that set the device up).

Comment: @Tyson I think you are misunderstanding the question. The music they want to sync is on the MacBook, not the device.

Comment: @CharlieSmith To clarify Tyson's comment, likely the best way to proceed would be copy the music you want from your iPod to your MacBook first (using third-party software), then proceed to set it up as a new iPod and sync whatever music you want from iTunes to your device. An iPod can only be set up to sync with one computer at a time.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, the issue is, that I have things other than music on the iPod currently, that i would rather not lose, 

if I click on the setup as new iPod option, does that wipe everything off the iPod ?

There is currently no music on the iPod, which is why I am trying to sync it, I just don't want to lose apps, app settings, and other things in doing this, if I can avoid it.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet would be to copy the iTunes library folder and the iPod backup from the computer that it was originally synced with to the macbook you want to sync to. This may get around iTunes wanting to force it to be step as new.

If you have never backed up your iPod then plug it into the computer you originally synced it with and perform a backup in iTunes. You can then use iTunes preferences to find where the backup was stored and copy this to the new macbook.

Then choose restore from backup on the macbook and theoretically it should re-setup the iPod in the same configuration as now and also allow you to use the macbook as the current syncing computer